# "To consolidate cost"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, nouns, word-usage, collocation

Is it correct to use the expression "consolidate cost" when you add cost figures in a specific period of time? The context is a description of what a piece of code is doing:

> consolidate cost over several periods

I've found the following definition of *consolidate*:

> to bring together (separate parts) into a single or unified whole; unite; combine: *They consolidated their three companies*.

But a Google search for "consolidate cost" only returns 12 600 results  which is usually an indication of a wrong usage.

Comment: Better, "*consolidate the costs*" (21,200 results): "#Obamacare is going to consolidate the costs" - Twitter; "We also had to fully consolidate the costs associated with administration" ...

Comment: Try "consolidate costs", plural, and you'll get very different results; in accounting one consolidates two or more things from different categories under one heading. The *result*, however, may be described as *consolidated cost*, in the singular, or *consolidated costs*, in the plural.

Comment: @StoneyB In the context, it's a verb, not an adj., right?

Comment: *Consolidated*, with the *d*, is a past (passive) participle, which is both a verb and an adjective, just as in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as business is concerned, *to consolidate cost* is not an incorrect usage, only that as StoneyB suggested in the comments above, it would be more appropriate to use the plural of *cost* since you will be bringing together different cost figures for a specific period of time.

However, the term *costs* usually refers to various accounts and if you wish to be specific you could say, for example, *to consolidate salary costs* or *consolidation of transport costs*.